# Debezium MS SQL Server connector issues

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Kafka newbie here.

**Environment setup**

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Kafka is installed locally on the machine within the home folder. Both Kafka and Zookeeper services are running.

I am trying to configure the Kafka connect to connect to database hosted within a SQL Server container that I built with the command below

`docker run --name SQL19 -p 1433:1433  -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"  -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password258*"  -e "MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=True" -v ~/SqlDockerVol/userdatabase:/userdatabase  -v ~/SqlDockerVol/sqlbackups:/sqlbackups -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-lat`est

The container is running and can connect successfully.

I enabled the CDC on the database level and on the table level.

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db
GO
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
    @source_schema = N'dbo',
    @source_name   = N'WorkQueue',
    @role_name     = NULL,
    @supports_net_changes = 1
```

**Connector properties file**

```
name= DebeziumSQLServerconnector 
connector.class= io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector 
database.hostname=linuxdesktop 
database.port= 1433 
database.user= sa 
database.password= Password258* 
database.dbname= mydb 
database.server.name= linuxdesktop 
table.include.list= dbo.WorkQueue 
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers= linuxdesktop:9092 
database.history.kafka.topic= dbhistory.mydb
```

**connect-standalone.properties plugin.path**

plugin.path=/home/vinu/kafka-server/connector

I copied all the .JAR files into the plugin.path

I then tried to start the connector with the command below

```
~/kafka-server/bin/connect-standalone.sh ~/kafka-server/config/connect-standalone.properties  DebeziumSQLServerconnector.properties
```

But process fails to start and get the following error message

> 2021-03-15 13:36:36,752] ERROR Failed to create job for
> DebeziumSQLServerconnector.properties
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:110) [2021-03-15
> 13:36:36,753] ERROR Stopping after connector error
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:121)
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any
> class that implements Connector and which name matches
> io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector , available
> connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class
> io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector,
> name='io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector',
> version='1.4.2.Final', encodedVersion=1.4.2.Final, type=source,
> typeName='source',
> location='file:/home/vinu/kafka-server/connector/debezium-connector-sqlserver/'},
> PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=sink, typeName='sink',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector',
> version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector',
> version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector',
> version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='2.7.0',
> encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=connector, typeName='connector',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=sink, typeName='sink',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}     at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:118)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to
> find any class that implements Connector and which name matches
> io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector , available
> connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class
> io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector,
> name='io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector',
> version='1.4.2.Final', encodedVersion=1.4.2.Final, type=source,
> typeName='source',
> location='file:/home/vinu/kafka-server/connector/debezium-connector-sqlserver/'},
> PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=sink, typeName='sink',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector',
> version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector',
> version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector',
> version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='2.7.0',
> encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=connector, typeName='connector',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=sink, typeName='sink',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector,
> name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector',
> version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source',
> location='classpath'}     at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.connectorClass(Plugins.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConnector(Plugins.java:180)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.getConnector(AbstractHerder.java:572)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:342)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

What could be the problem?

**NOTE**
All Kafka components are installed locally on the machine. The only container in my setup is SQL Server.

[image]
[image]

Comment: According to the output, your plugin path is `/home/vinu/kafka-server/connector/`, not `/usr/share/java`, and properties files don't use colons for key-value pairs.... But output that starts with `available connectors are` clearly lists the connector you're trying to use... Note, `kafka:9092` isn't going to work on the host machine where `localhost:1433` is the database connection string. I suggest running Debezium docker container

Comment: thanks. correct plugin path and changed : to  = in the properties file. Also database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers to localhost:9092 (database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers:localhost:9092 )but still gets the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `available connectors` lists the class, so your plugins are fine.

You have a space issue. Notice the log output comma placement

`matches io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector ,`

Remove trailing whitespace from the whole property file and leading whitespace before values

Answer (score 0):

you must not place the connector JARs into `/home/vinu/kafka-server/connector` but into `/home/vinu/kafka-server/connector/debezium-sqlserver-connector` or any other name.
Connectors are not put to `plugin.path` but each connector to a separate dir in the `plugin.path`.

Comment: Thanks Jiri. Please see the images added to the original post...

Comment: I agree with the other answer